# Populate JTable with array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I have a multidimensional array of integers (`int[][] model = new int[9][9]`) and a table (`JTable table = new JTable(9, 9)`.

How can I populate the table with the values of `model`?

I have tried

```
// Populate JTable with data from model
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    this.table = this.table.addRow(this.model[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom `TabelModel` and read values directly from array:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTable table = new JTable(3, 3);

        final int[][] values = new int[][] {
            {1,2,3},
            {2,3,4},
            {3,4,5},
        };

        table.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return values[rowIndex][columnIndex];
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I am doing this inside an actionlistener, so I get the error `Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater` and I cannot access a variable defined outside of `this.table.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {}`

Comment: First error related to `@Override` attribute. Do you really use JDK less than 1.5? The second can be fixed easy: just create regular class inherited from `AbstractTableModel` and pass array to constructor.

Answer (score 2):

A `JTable` works with Objects, not primitives.

Convert the int values to an Integer and add the data to the `DefaultTableModel` of your table:

So the basic code might be something like:

```
int[][] values = new int[][]
{
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9, 10, 11, 12},
};

int columns = values[0].length;

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, columns)
{
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        return Integer.class; // number will be displayed right aligned
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    int[] rowData = values[i];
    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

    for (int j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++)
        row.addElement( new Integer( rowData[j] ) );

    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

> I have a multidimensional array of integers

Another option might be to create your data in an Object array, then you can just do:

```
String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel()
{
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        return Integer.class;
    }
};
model.setDataVector(values, columnNames);

JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Comment: What if I already created my JTable, but just want to change all the values at once?

Comment: Then you just change the model of the table by using the `setModel(..)` method.  Or you remove all the rows from the existing model using the `setRowCount(0)` and then you add back in each row one at a time.